# Error in Solr 9.1.0 : Document contains at least one immense term in field="text" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766)

Tags: solr, solrj

How could I fix this error to index large files in Solr 9.1.0 ? Some of the solution found online are either for older version or not working with latest version of solr 9.1.0:
This error happens in this field name = "textcontent"

SCHEMA.XML :

```
<field name="textcontent" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="goog" type="string" uninvertible="false" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/> -->
<copyField source="textcontent" dest="goog"/>
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer name="standard"/>
            <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter name="lowercase"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer name="standard"/>
            <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter name="synonymGraph" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter name="lowercase"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

FULL ERROR MESSAGE:

> Exception writing document id 2222 to the index; possible analysis
> error: Document contains at least one immense term in
> field="textcontent" **(whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length
> 32766)**, all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not
> produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[37,
> 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 55, 13, 10, 37, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67,
> -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 13, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 960117.
> Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which
> is too large  at
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:822)